# Set $PATH For /bin/false user

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a sensu user:

`sensu:x:496:496:Sensu Monitoring Framework:/opt/sensu:/bin/false`

Its `$PATH` is:
`/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I want to update its `PATH`, so that while sensu triggers my check script, it will use my side installed python version (installed under `/usr/local/bin`), hence I want to set sensu's `PATH` to:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

However, I've edited both `/opt/sensu/.bashrc` and `/opt/sensu/.profile`, didn't work; I've read online ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment)), `.bashrc` will got sourced only after login for both interactive/non-interactive users, however, sensu as a `/bin/false` user, `.profile` will got sourced after user login with bash, my understanding is it doesn't have a login shell as all, but how could I achieve my goal of setting `$PATH` for it?

BTW, by running `sudo su - sensu -s /bin/bash` I saw .profile got sourced correctly, however this makes little sense for me since while sensu client runs my python check script it won't have bash.

Can I modify `/etc/passwd` to change `/bin/false` to `/bin/bash`, will this cause problem Please?

Comment: This *might* work: `sudo -u sensu PATH="/usr/local/bin:$(getconf PATH)" python program.py` -- check your `sudo(1)` and `sudoers(5)` man pages.

Comment: Thanks this will work, but the problem for me is, while sensu runs the check scripts, it will run as sensu user, and I don't have the control it runs the way you mentioned above..

Answer (score 1):

As you already noticed, the shell for your sensu user is `/bin/false`, so it doesn't have a shell at all. You could give it a real shell like /bin/bash, and at the same time block the account (use `passwd -l`) so you can't login with the account remotely, thus making it a bit more safe.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser! I am really afraid of breaking my instance, before I proceed with your suggestion, can I make sure:

1. Changing from /bin/false to /bin/bash and passwd -l sensu won't break the function of sensu monitorering?
2. "sensu" user is the one to run sensu services, once I finish #1 above, should I logout sensu and relogin it?

Comment: I doubt if it would break it; besides, if things stop working, you can always revert the shell to /bin/false. Usually these users exist only to run the monitoring processes separate from other processes, and don't require a shell. You should restart your sensu monitoring service(s), yes.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work...

Comment: Hmm. You may then have to change the script that calls your sensu monitoring script to include the correct PATH. Ther are 2 last resorts: symlink your python version to /usr/bin (unless that conflicts), or change the global PATH in /etc/profile or similar system-wide shell initialization.

Comment: Adding a python 2.7.10 symlink might possibly break CentOS, it has built-in py 2.6.6.

Comment: Refer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4#centos-and-its-design-choices

Answer (score 1):

To update the $PATH, the following line needs to be added

***export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin***

Depending on machine type and server/client the file name would change:

**For redhat machine:**

- sensu-client

  ```
   /etc/sysconfig/sensu-client
  ```
- sensu-server

  ```
   /etc/sysconfig/sensu-server
  ```

**For debian machines:**

- sensu-client

  ```
   /etc/default/sensu-client
  ```
- sensu-server

  ```
   /etc/default/sensu-server
  ```

Comment: It is best to use `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. This way, when two commands with the same name exist, one provided by the OS and the other one a custom one, precedence is given to the custom one.